# After Slide Up/Down Animation Textview onClickListener not working

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm using Slide Up/Down Animation for my four `TextView`. Following is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2.0" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewblue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="blue" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textVieworange"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/orange"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="orange" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewpink"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pink"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="pink" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewgreen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/green"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="green" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and Following is my Class

```
    public class HomeScreenActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView textViewblue, textVieworange, textViewpink,
            textViewgreen;
    Animation mAnimation_up, mAnimation_down;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
        mAnimation_up = new TranslateAnimation(
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.6f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);
        mAnimation_up.setDuration(1000);
        mAnimation_up.setRepeatCount(-1);
        mAnimation_up.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        mAnimation_up.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

        mAnimation_down = new TranslateAnimation(
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.6f);
        mAnimation_down.setDuration(1000);
        mAnimation_down.setRepeatCount(-1);
        mAnimation_down.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        mAnimation_down.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
       initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {

        textViewblue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewblue);
        textVieworange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textVieworange);
        textViewpink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewpink);
        textViewgreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewgreen);

        textViewblue .setOnClickListener(this);
        textVieworange .setOnClickListener(this);
        textViewpink .setOnClickListener(this);
        textViewgreen .setOnClickListener(this);

        textViewblue .setAnimation(mAnimation_down);
        textViewpink .setAnimation(mAnimation_down);
        textVieworange .setAnimation(mAnimation_up);
        textViewgreen .setAnimation(mAnimation_up);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intentmenu;
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.textViewblue:
            Toast.makeText(this, "blue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.textVieworange:
             Toast.makeText(this, "orange", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.textViewpink:
            Toast.makeText(this, "pink", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.textViewgreen:
            Toast.makeText(this, "reeng", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that when any `TextView`slide for int position means when animation starts the `onClickListener` works only at its XML position not for its updated position.
Please suggest me the solution for that, how can I detect the updated position for to detect onClickListener on `TextView`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's a bit complicated to make it. As you're using [View animation system](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html), the behavior is under expectation. Although the Views are translated to other places, they're just being 
**drawn** there. From the system's perspective, they're in fact always at the original place where you define in xml file. If you want the click event at the new place, you should use the new [property animation system](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, can you give me the any simple link for reference

Comment: see http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html

Answer (score 0):

The onClickListener is not working because views are shifted from their original place due to animation. To solve this create a same layout below your animation and initially make its Gravity as GONE and when your animation finishes up make its Gravity as Visible and your animation layout visibility as Gone. 
also be careful that all the id's of animation and original layout would not be same.